# How to print students name in ascending according to marks

Tags: c++

I had sort the mark for all tests, quizzes, assignments and final exam in ASCENDING order. But I don't know how to display all student's name in ascending order based on their mark for each tests, quizzes, assignments and final exam.

Below are my code to sort each mark for tests, quizzes, assignments and final exam in ascending order. How to change the code so that it will display the students name, not the marks for each tests, quizzes, assignments and final exam?

Please, help. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//global constant
const int NUM_STUDENTS=5;//row
const int NUM_SCORES=4;//col
string name[5]={"Hani","Haziq","Aiman","Farah","Sabrina"};
string mark[4]={"test","quiz","assignment","final exam"};

//Function prototypes
void ascenDescen(double [ ][NUM_SCORES],int);

int main ( )
{
    cout<<"This program will help you keep track of your academic record!"<<endl;

    double scores[NUM_STUDENTS][NUM_SCORES]=
     {{9.0,2.7,16.0,78.0},
      {7.4,2.7,19.0,88.0},
      {8.9,3.5,17.5,93.7},
      {10.0,3.0,19.5,64.8},
      {6.3,3.0,16.0,74.2}};

    //function call
    ascenDescen(scores,NUM_STUDENTS);

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"THANK YOU."<<endl;

    return 0;
}

void ascenDescen (double table[][NUM_SCORES],int rows)
{
    //for ascending 
    cout<<"Press ENTER to sort the mark for all tests, quizzes, assignments and final exam in ASCENDING order : \n\n"; 
    char ch;
    ch=cin.get();

    double ascen;
    for(int col=0;col<NUM_SCORES;col++)
    {
        for(int row=0;row<NUM_STUDENTS;row++)
        {
             for(int j=row+1;j<NUM_STUDENTS;++j)
             {
                if(table[row][col]>table[j][col])
                {
                    ascen=table[row][col];
                    table[row][col]=table[j][col];
                    table[j][col]=ascen;
                }
             }
        }

        cout<<mark[col]<<" mark in ASCENDING order : \n";
        for(int row=0;row<NUM_STUDENTS;row++)
        {
            cout<<"  ";
            cout<<table[row][col];
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
     cout<<"________________________"<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Are you permitted to sort the data using std::sort?

Comment: i never learnt about it actually. how to do it?

Comment: [`std::sort` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). You will find it helpful to bundle your data into an array of a `class` or a `struct` rather than a 2D array. It makes the sorting much, much easier.

Comment: but i must use array in the code.

Comment: Maybe try `std::lexiographical_compare` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare

Comment: If you have to use the array it gets much more complicated. Has your instructor covered any simple sorting techniques in class o assigned readings on sorting algorithms? If so, odds are good you're expected to implement one of them. Start by sorting a 1D array of numbers. Once you have that working you need to figure out how to sort one column in a 2D array. And when you have that figured out you need to figure out how to swap rows instead of numbers while sorting. Any one of those problems will make for a good question. But start with figuring out what sorting algorithm the instructor expects

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ read student sort ascending order".  There should be a plethora of them on the internet and StackOverflow.  I have answered many of them.  Always search first before posting on StackOverflow.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I had search in the internet to solve this problem. I also had watch many youtube video to get the idea. I had stuck and keep trying to solve that problem for about 3 days. And last night, I find out about this website. And trust me, the first thing that I did was searching the similar question as mine. But I did not find it, maybe because i use incorrect keyword. And maybe because I am too tired searching the answer alone. So I post my question here.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am not hoping that someone will post a complete code to answer my question. I am just hoping that someone will give me idea to solve it, like the comments above. Thank you for your advice. Next time, I will search more detail or use many type of keywords before ask someone's help.

Comment: @user4581301 My instructor does not covered any simple sorting techniques or assigned readings on sorting algorithms. And sadly, we have finished our silibus. But thank you for your suggestion. I will study about the std::sort documentation, and use it in future.

Comment: @SzymonO Thank you for your suggestion. Really appreciate it. Will definitely study about it and use it in future.

Comment: See my answer.  The answer uses a `struct` to model the student, `std::vector` to contain the marks and also as a database of students.  There are two calls to `std::sort`, one uses the default ordering, and the other uses a custom ordering.  You can use a custom ordering function to change the ordering (such as descending order for the marks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//global constant
const int NUM_STUDENTS=5;//row
const int NUM_SCORES=4;//col
string name[5]={"Hani","Haziq","Aiman","Farah","Sabrina"};
string mark[4]={"test","quiz","assignment","final exam"};

struct student {

};

//Function prototypes
void ascenDescen(double [ ][NUM_SCORES],int);

int main ( )
{
    cout<<"This program will help you keep track of your academic record!"<<endl;

    double scores[NUM_STUDENTS][NUM_SCORES]=
     {{9.0,2.7,16.0,78.0},
      {7.4,2.7,19.0,88.0},
      {8.9,3.5,17.5,93.7},
      {10.0,3.0,19.5,64.8},
      {6.3,3.0,16.0,74.2}};

    //function call
    ascenDescen(scores,NUM_STUDENTS);

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"THANK YOU."<<endl;

    return 0;
}

void ascenDescen (double table[][NUM_SCORES],int rows)
{
    //for ascending 
    cout<<"Press ENTER to sort the mark for all tests, quizzes, assignments and final exam in ASCENDING order : \n\n"; 
    cin.get();

    double ascen;
    string temp1[5] = name;
    string temp2;
    for(int col=0;col<NUM_SCORES;col++)
    {
        for(int row=0;row<NUM_STUDENTS;row++)
        {
             for(int j=row+1;j<NUM_STUDENTS;++j)
             {
                if(table[row][col]>table[j][col])
                {
                    ascen=table[row][col];
                    temp2 = temp1[row];
                    table[row][col]=table[j][col];
                    temp1[row] = temp1[j]; 
                    table[j][col]=ascen;
                    temp1[j] = temp2;

                }
             }
        }

        cout<<mark[col]<<" mark in ASCENDING order : \n";
        for(int row=0;row<NUM_STUDENTS;row++)
        {
            cout<<"  ";
            cout << temp1[row] << " " <<table[row][col];
            cout<<endl;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; i++) 
        {
        temp1[i] = name[i];
        }
    }
     cout<<"________________________"<<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A rule of thumb:  If you need parallel arrays, chances are you should have a `vector` of `struct`.

Let's try modeling the data using a `Student` structure:

```
struct Student
{
  std::string name;
  std::vector<int> marks;
};
```

Thus far, every `Student` *has a* name and *has some* marks.  The *has-a* relationship indicates *composition*.  The *is-a* relationship indicates inheritance.

Let's add a sort method for the marks.  The students will be easier to order by marks, if the marks are sorted.

```
struct Student
{
  //...
  void sort_marks()
  {
    std::sort(marks.begin(), marks.end()); // Assume default of `std::less<int>`
  }
};
```

To perform an ordering other than the default, we'll need to define a custom ordering function:

```
bool Order_By_Marks(const Student& a, const Student& b)
{
    bool a_is_less_than_b = true;
    unsigned int quantity_of_marks = a.marks.size();
    if (b.marks.size() < quantity_of_marks)
    {
       quantity_of_marks = b.marks.size();
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < quantity_of_marks; ++i)
    {
       if (a.marks[i] > b.marks[i])
       {
         a_is_less_than_b = false;
         break;
       }
    }
    return a_is_less_than_b;
}
```

To sort a database of `Student` by marks:

```
std::vector<Student> database;
// ... input students ...
for (i = 0; i < database.size(); ++i)
{
    database[i].sort_marks();
}
std::sort(database.begin(), database.end(), Order_By_Marks);
```

You'll need to walk through the code with a debugger to verify the ordering of the student marks and also the ordering of the students by mark.